# get a range of objects with binary search

Tags: search, binary-search, range

I have some data like this:

```
ID  Value  
1   AAA  
1   ABC  
2   dasd  
2   dsfdsf  
2   dsfsd  
3   df  
3   dwqef
```

they are objects(not plain text).
and i want to get all objects with the ID = 2.
I can do a binary binary search and get the index 3,but how can i get (2 and 4) is there any efficient algorithm?
the real problem has lists with about one Million items.

any language except bf and lisp can help.

Comment: If I understand correctly your binary search returns the index where a new element with given value will be placed. If you are only interested in the index range this can be faster then my solution when there are a high number of values per id. My solution will be a little faster if you need the values (not just the index range) or the number of values per id is low.

It's possible that your type conversion (integer to float) can decrease performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Map wich maps an id to a collection of values;

```
Map:
1 => { AAA, ABC }
2 => { dasd, dsfdsf, dsfsd }
...
```

This will have an efficient lookup time of O(1). You can do the binary search as well, but lookups will be less efficient.

**Binary search algorithm:**

First you create a sorted list (arraylist, linkedlist, etc). It must be sorted on the id. Then you do a standard binary search to find one element that matches id. Then you traverse both upwards and downwards the list until element does not match id. This will find all objects with the given id.

Example list:

```
List Index, Object
0    Id=1 Value=A
1    Id=2 Value=B 
2    Id=2 Value=C
3    Id=3 Value=D
4    Id=3 Value=E
```

Binary search returns index 2. Now loop downwards will first find element 1: Id=2 which matches, then element 0: Id=1 which does not match and therefore terminates the downward loop. The upward loop first finds element 3: Id=3 which does not match. This terminates the upward loop.

Comment: +1 for my previous solution, I am doing such a thing to avoid using a map.my goal is to use less memory with good performance.

Comment: your answer helped me to answer myself.I will add it to the original question.